# How to find words using a regular expression regardless of Location

Tags: regex

Is there a way to find a word regardless of location?

For example, let's say I have the following 3 sentences:

1. I love Pie
2. Pie Loves me.
3. I love Pie today.

I want to write a Regular Expression to find the word Pie that would work for all 3 scenarios. Would do you guys suggest?

This is what I have tried:

1. Pie (Only works if Pie is at the beginning and nothing else comes after)
2. (Pie)* Same result as part 1.
3. .....(Pie)  - This only works if there are exactly 5 characters before the word "Pie." Which does not help me much because there could be any number of characters.

Edit Regarding Final Solution: I ended up using `.*Pie.*` and I just wanted to explain what this does to others who are new to coding/regex.

What this is saying is that any character, appearing zero or more times and preceding the word Pie, followed by another single character appearing zero or more times. This allowed me to find "Pie" anywhere in any of the sentences.

Comment: please add a little more detail, the regex for 'Pie' would match all three of these cases - also if you're unsure you can always take a look at http://rubular.com/ which is a great tool for trying out regexes

Comment: What have you already tried, and how has that differed to what you expected to happen?

Comment: I'd suggest you make an effort to write that regex. You could at least make a basic effort to do some work yourself, instead of expecting us to act as a regex-writing service for you.

Comment: Edited Post above.

Comment: I upvoted that comment only because it was funny :)

Comment: Did you try the regex? My comment wasn't only funny. :-) It matches in all three of the sample phrases you posted, and will also match if you change *Pie* to *pie* in any one of them.

Comment: While it does in the website that you posted, rubular.com, it does not work in the business intelligence tool that I am using, Pentaho. This is why I reached out to stackoverflow. I am new to regex and thought I was doing something wrong, but no, it's Pentaho :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your updated question I'm not sure what tool you're using for your Regex matching. Most tools (e.g. grep) will match it if any part of the line matches.

However if your tool for some reason starts at the beginning you can use the .* pattern to match anything where . is any character and * is any number of times (e.g. .*Pie).

For posterity: http://rubular.com/ is a great place to test out Regexes and I've found it to be super useful.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! :) Thank you for the website recommendation as well. I am new to regex :)